# SonarQube Projects disappearing after docker restart

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sonarqube

I have created a docker compose file which starts Postgres and SonarQube. I have configured SonarQube to use Postgres as the default database. When docker starts, I can run analysis on a project of mine using sonar scanner. The results are then published to SonarQube. I can then view the project and its results.

However when I restart docker, the project disappears. I know that the project is still there because SonarQube server displays '0 of 6 shown' under projects and there is a 'Show More' link. However I cant seem to find a way to see that project. I have also logged in as admin and tried.

I also tried setting up the project first on sonarqube using the create new project method by providing the project name and key. I still dont see that project available after dockercompose is restarted. I have made sure that the project had public visibility

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgresql:
    image: 'bitnami/postgresql:latest'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - 'postgresql_data:/bitnami'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
  sonarqube:
    image: bitnami/sonarqube:latest
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
    environment:
      - POSTGRESQL_HOST=postgresql
      - POSTGRESQL_PORT=5432
      - POSTGRESQL_ROOT_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRESQL_CLIENT_CREATE_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_sonarqube
      - POSTGRESQL_CLIENT_CREATE_DATABASE_USERNAME=bn_sonarqube
      - POSTGRESQL_CLIENT_CREATE_DATABASE_PASSWORD=bitnami1234
      - SONARQUBE_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_sonarqube
      - SONARQUBE_DATABASE_USER=bn_sonarqube
      - SONARQUBE_DATABASE_PASSWORD=bitnami1234
    volumes:
      - sonarqube_data:/bitnami
volumes:
  sonarqube_data:
    driver: local
  postgresql_data:
    driver: local
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: did you restart `container` or `docker` service ?

Comment: i start using docker-compose up and shutdown using docker-compose down. Irrespective of that, why can I see the 6 projects there? I did scan 6 different projects while trying out various things. The data is persisted in the db. I cant seem to see it on the screen? I also gave full permissions group access to the admin user.

Answer (score 0):

you should mount the data from sonar and the data from your database so when you

```
docker-compose down
```

data won't be removed

## docker-compose

```
   volumes:
     - ./sonar/data:/opt/sonarqube/data
```

if you are using docker-compose try this on sonar and the data from database and link the database to sonarqube the configuration also should be in the runtime

can you show us your docker-compose ?

Comment: i added the docker compose file in my post. I tried adding the path /opt/sonarqube/data to the volume parameter earlier and that didnt work either.

Comment: it looks like i had the wrong volume setup done. after your comment, i looked into that closely and was able to see the projects scanned before.